# Display a custom message When 2 specific product category are in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, custom-taxonomy

In Woocommerce, I'm trying to make a function that displays a message above the cart page **when products with both categories are in the cart**.

I'm trying to modify code that I found here but now it already shows the message when one of the categories is added instead of both:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'allclean_add_checkout_content', 12 );
function allclean_add_checkout_content() {

    $special_cat2 = 'test-cat2';
    $special_cat3 = 'test-cat3';
    $bool = false;

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $item = $cart_item['data'];
        if ( has_term( $special_cat2 && $special_cat3, 'product_cat', $item->id ) )
            $bool = true;
    }

    if ($bool)
        echo '<div class="cartmessage">Warning! Beware of combining these materials!</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some mistakes in your code like `has_term()` does not support 2 terms separated with `&&` and to get the product id from cart for custom taxonomy as product categories you need `$cart_item['product_id']` instead that will also work with product variations……

To make that works when both product categories are in cart use this instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'allclean_add_checkout_content', 12 );
function allclean_add_checkout_content() {

    $product_cats = array('test-cat2','test-cat3'); 
    $found1 = $found2 = false;

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // The needed working product ID is $cart_item['product_id']  <====
        if ( has_term( $product_cats[0], 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) )
            $found1 = true;
        elseif ( has_term( $product_cats[1], 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) )
            $found2 = true;
    }

    if ( $found1 && $found2 )
        echo '<div class="cartmessage">Warning! Beware of combining these materials!</div>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). **Tested and works**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how can i make $found true only when both categories are in the cart?

Comment: @Cel you need both categories to be true, or just one of them?

Comment: i would like both

Comment: @cel I haven't read well your question at start, as I was focusing on your code… so welcome…

Answer (score 2):

The command `$special_cat2 && $special_cat3` is an `AND` calculation of two variables. Using the operator `&&` will make PHP convert both variables to boolean. The result of this command is therefore also a boolean and `true` in your case. So your call is equivalent to:

```
has_term(TRUE, 'product_cat', $item->id)
```

This is clearly not what you want.

What you want to do instead is to call `has_term()` twice for each category:

```
if (has_term($special_cat2, 'product_cat', $item->id) && has_term($special_cat3, 'product_cat', $item->id)) {
    ... // Now both terms are present
}
```

The operaor `&&` is different to a simple AND (`&`), because it includes lazyness. This means, that if the first call of `has_term()` returns `false` already, the second call will not be done. This is perfect to reduce loading time.